# Trim and Dictionary can not work together

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, trim

I have code like this, but:

- If I use `myDic.add Trim(cells(4,5)), key` --> I get an error.
- If I use `myDic.add cells(4,5), key` --> no error.

```vb
Dim MyDictionary As Scripting.Dictionary
Set MyDictionary = New Scripting.Dictionary

Do While Len(Temp.Cells(num, 1))) > 0
   "myDic.add Trim(cells(4,5)), key" 'Error Here
Loop
```

Is that we cannot use `Trim` when we use `Add` ? Thanks

Comment: You should post your actual code.

Comment: Did you try the solution given?

Comment: found my issue is something else wrong not that point.

Comment: Just a headsup, you can use `Application.Trim` on a whole range at once before you would add them into a `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Trim (or typed function Trim$) with dict.add. There are a number of other errors with your code:

Get rid of the " around

```
"myDic.add Trim(cells(4,5)), key"
```

i.e.

```
 myDic.add Trim(cells(4,5)), key
```

Also, you add key first with dictionaries, though I don't know what you mean by key here. Where is it defined and do you mean key for the value you wish to add to the dictionary?

And, you don't increment the cell it is always cells(4,5) . If this was a key they must be unique.

Traditionally I would expect something like

```
dict.add key, Trim$(ws.cells(i,5))
```

where `key` is unique and defined, `ws` is a variable holding the parent sheet name, `i` (or maybe `num`?) is an Long type variable to allow you to change the value being added, assuming you want to add a cell value in a loop to a dictionary.